# Row_Number() over 2 billion records (Teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working with a Teradata warehouse, and I am using row_number in one of my sql scripts. The record set I am trying to use my script on is larger than the maximum of the integer value threshold. What to do in such a situation?

(casting the "row_number() over (par..)" expression to bigint did not work)

If you have found a solution for this problem in another DBMS, then I also welcome your solution as it might work in Teradata too.

Comment: I find it strange that Row_Number() doesn't return a bigint to begin with, which is what happens in MSSQL.  I can't find any documentation on teradata's Row_Number() function.

Comment: Same, I searched the http://www.info.teradata.com/ with a full-text search, but couldn't find any documentation. 
Currently the only solution I can find is partitioning my dataset and executing the script on each datasets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that just casting the value would work.

If not, try this:

```
select sum(cast(1 as bigint)) over (order by . . . Rows Unbounded Preceding)
```

Or, alternatively,

```
select csum(cast(1 as bigint), <order by column here>)
```

Comment: It does not work. It first calculates the sum, so the "row_number" will be the row count for each row.

Comment: select sum(cast(1 as bigint)) over (order by sub_id)  from  TMP.JunctionTable;

this will return the record count, record count times.

Comment: @kori0129 . . . I found the answer here (http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/over-partition-with-order-by-in-teradata-how-to-used).  Teradata supports the `order by` syntax, but does something different from the standard.  Fortunately, there appears to be a work-around.