# Generate Sequence number for each row while inserting records into table

Tags: sql, teradata

I am new to Teradata have task like having millions of records to insert into the table there is no limitation for records so how to jenerate sequence number for each row while inserting records into table

Answer (score 0):

you can use identity column..!!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column

Answer (score -1):

Consider using either the `ROW_NUMBER()` or Cumulative Sum via the `SUM()` window aggregate function. You can find details on these functions in the Teradata Manuals or reviewing the response to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173192/row-number-over-2-billion-records-teradata) on StackOverflow.